# Enabling OpenGL in Java makes edges of JPanel with graphics get cut off

Tags: java, windows, swing, opengl, graphics2d

I'm making a game using Java Graphics2D for a school assignment. When I add the following line to the beginning of my main method to improve performance,

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
```

the edges of the graphics panel get cut off.

I made a small program to show the effect:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    public Main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("OpenGL off");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));
        g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 800, 600));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Enables hardware acceleration
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
    
        new Main();
    }
}
```

No OpenGL:
[image: OpenGL off]

OpenGL enabled:
[image: OpenGL on]

The problem shows up on Windows but not Mac.

Java Version: Java 11, OS: Windows 10

<sub>*EDIT: The problem also occurs with Java 14*</sub>

Comment: What version of Java are you compiling with?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Java 11

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the problem with Java 8 and Windows 10.  I suggest that you start your application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method to make sure the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: Why are you using that property in the first place? Are you experiencing any performance issue with the Direct3D pipeline?

Comment: @Holger I get low FPS if I don't enable OpenGL for hardware acceleration

Comment: Which Java version, which OS version? Any UI (DPI) scaling going on?

Comment: @Holger Java 11, Windows 10. No DPI scaling

Comment: Still can’t reproduce. The only thing that might be different (and can influence the result) is the graphics card driver.

Comment: Try to change System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true"); with System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some documentation by Oracle saying that **this command may not work with some hardware configurations or versions of java.** It's more of a convenience thing, as you said and you may just be using it with the wrong version of Java or one that does not support this command. **I suggest that you look at this documentation:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html
You may need to **upgrade your Java version** or just **use your MAC OS** since that seems to be working well. I recommend reading the documentation as that has some solid information. Long story short, it's probably a problem on your end and you should either research in order to find an alternative or just settle. I am also a student who is in the beginning of my programming career and I just decided to try and solve a problem, I hope I helped?